# Background Video Sizing Issue

Tags: html, css, video, background

I'm trying to get a background video to size correctly, but it's acting real strange. The site I'm working on is this: http://evolfo.github.io/Brooklyn-Birdhouse/index.html

There is unused space on the top of the video (I have no idea how it got there) and I'm having trouble getting the video to fill up the full container 100% of the time.

Here's the CSS for the video:

```
video { 
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: it looks ok to me in chrome - what do you mean when you say you cannot get the video to fill up the container 100% of the time?

Comment: just as an aside i noticed lots of inline styles in your html. You should move this into your style.css

Comment: I did not see this as well, nor on Chrome or IE

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a great solution, you can probably cover it up by using margin/padding features. Just add

```
margin: -10px 0px 0px 0px
```

to the css under video or put it inline in the code to have it push itself up over the unused space. You might need to adjust the -10px to a more exact amount that works.